# Pass data from jsp to html

Tags: html, database, jsp

So I have a form in my a.html file. I then pass these data to my b.jsp file and perform some queries (inserting to the database etc). Now I have another html file called "confirmation.html", which shows what were added to the database. How do I get the data from my b.jsp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML files are static. They can't display data dynamically. Use another JSP.

`b.jsp` should be a servlet instead. JSPs are view components, used to generate HTML markup. Servlets are controller components, used to contain Java code and, for example, insert and get data from the database.

The requests should that way:

1. GET request for ShowFormServlet. The ShowFormServlet forwards to showForm.jsp, which displays the form
2. POST request to InsertDataServlet to submit the form. The servlet inserts data in the database and sends a redirect to ShowDataServlet
3. GET request to ShowDataServlet. The ShowDataServlet gets the data from the database, stores them in a request attribute, and forwards to displayData.jsp. displayData.jsp generates HTML markup to display the data stored in the request attribute.

This is the MVC pattern.

To redirect, use `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()`. To forward from a servlet to a JSP, use `HttpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(...).forward()`.

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand what you're saying. Are you saying that there's no way I can get the data from b.jsp. If that's the case, then how do I display my confirmation page?

Comment: Do you understand at least that html files are completely static and thus can't display dynamic data? Do you understand that JSP files are like HTML files, but can display dynamic data? What don't you understand in what I posted?